# center text ignoring superscript

Tags: html, alignment, superscript

I have a table of center-aligned text. But some of the text includes superscripts.
Is there a way to make the text align and ignore the superscripts?

For example, in this code how to make the 2 align directly below the 1.

```css
td {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2<sup>hello</sup></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text in a span and the position the superscript text absolutely:

```css
td {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

td>span {
  position: relative;
}

span>sup {
  position: absolute;
  /* play with the below to line up your sup properly */
  top: -0.4em;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left:0.1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span>2<sup>hello</sup></span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```